# How do i set Qt5Config.cmake path in fedora 20?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, fedora, cmake-gui

I have already installed Qt5. I get the following error when I run cmake on the build files of an application.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

```
Qt5Config.cmake
qt5-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

I understand I need to specify a path. Can any 1 please help me with the exact command of what I need to write and in which file do I need to change this? I am a newbie so please answer in detail and not refer any links. I can find the location of Qt5Config.cmake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any answer which does not give you any links is a bad answer. Make sure you get linked to http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.3/cmake-manual.html

Comment: @steveire how and what do I change so as to make the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to install prefix of qt5 in fedora? Please tell the syntax and where do i use it.

Comment: What is the path to the Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake file?

Comment: @steveire
home/usr/lib64/cmake/Qt5/

Comment: That's the wrong path. If  `home/usr/lib64/cmake/Qt5/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake` exists, then the package is broken.

Comment: I set the path I mentioned at Qt5_DIR. Yes, That worked.